# How to generate date range sequence without temp table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I want to convert some line of code from Oracle query to MSSQL.

```
   WITH DATE_MONTHS AS
(
  SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(TRUNC(TO_DATE(P_REQUIRED_DATE),'MON')), - LEVEL 
  +1),'DD-MON-YYYY') MONTHS FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= P_MONTH_RANG
)
SELECT * from DATE_MONTHS
```

Parameters:

- P_REQUIRED_DATE i.e sysdate
- P_MONTH_RANG  i.e 4

Result:

- 01-05-2017
- 01-04-2017
- 01-03-2017
- 01-02-2017

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way is to use tally table and generate like below:

```
declare @P_Required_Date date = '2015-05-01'
declare @P_Month_Rang int = 4

Select top (@P_Month_Rang) Dts = DateAdd(month, -(Row_Number() over(order by (Select NULL))-1), @P_Required_Date) from 
        master..spt_values s1, master..spt_values s2
```

Output as below:

```
    +------------+
    |    Dts     |
    +------------+
    | 2015-05-01 |
    | 2015-04-01 |
    | 2015-03-01 |
    | 2015-02-01 |
    +------------+
```

Your CTE approach:

```
declare @P_Required_Date date = '2015-05-01'
declare @P_Month_Rang int = 4

;with Date_Months as
(
    Select @P_Required_Date as Dates, 1 as Levl

    Union all

    Select DateAdd(MONTH,-1, Dates), Levl+1 as Levl  from Date_Months
        where Levl < @P_Month_Rang
)
Select convert(varchar(10), dates, 103) from Date_Months
```

For converting to your dd-mm-yyyy format one way is to do convert with option 103 or use Format.

Comment: May want to show how to do DD-MM-YYYY formatting, as specified in the question... it's useful to know too.

Answer (score 1):

Another option using Stacked Ctes

```
declare @fromdate date = '20150501';
declare @months int = 4;

;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (@months) 
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(month,-(row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1),@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo cross join n as tenK
  order by [Date] desc
)
select [Date] = convert(char(10),[date],105)
from dates;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/UUW2271

returns:

```
+------------+
|    Date    |
+------------+
| 01-05-2015 |
| 01-04-2015 |
| 01-03-2015 |
| 01-02-2015 |
+------------+
```

Benchmarks & Performance testing: [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)

Comment: nice article to understanding more about different ways. thanks